# Background image for UITableView on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uicolor, ios-universal-app

I got settings view in my iOS app which presented by `UITableView`. This app is universal, so you can run it on iPhone and on iPad. This table should be with custom background. And use this code for setting image for background:

```
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_bg"]];
```

This is OK for iPhone:

[image]

But on iPad this background is grey!

[image]

Why? How should i set custom background for iPad? Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow a known difference between iPhone and iPad UITableView behaviour in the grouped mode. Use this code instead (or similar):

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundView)]) {
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    UIView* bkgView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds] autorelease];
    bkgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:...]];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:bkgView];

}
```

Comment: What or where is the image you referenced? Or you mean that as a placeholder?